# Search mails for multiple labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I've been using GMAIL for a long time and I have many mails with multiple labels. I am being migrated to Outlook and mails will be moved over and into Outlook folders based on labels, BUT only the first label name will be considered. So if I have a mail with 2 (or 3 labels) they will get put into a folder named after the first label.
How can I search GMAIL for all mails that will be affected by this, i.e. those with  label count > 1? I will have to modify all those mails so that they all have only one label and then they'll end up in the 'correct' Outlook folder.
Any ideas?